# Count the same values in column SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want to make that my query would count same values in column, and then would order by descending order. My code does not work :/.

```
SELECT 
    F_PURCHASE.PID, D_PITEMS.ID, COUNT(D_PITEMS.ITEMID), D_PITEMS.ITEMNAME 
FROM 
    F_PURCHASE 
INNER JOIN 
    D_PITEMS ON F_PURCHASE.PID = D_PITEMS.ID 
GROUP BY 
    D_PITEMS.ITEMID
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired result. There are many ways to approach this question without the knowledge of your expected output.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: If you aren't aggregating the field with a formula (`sum()`, `count()`, `avg()`, etc) then it belongs in your group by. Otherwise you may get funky results.

Answer (score 1):

Your GROUP BY should contain all the fields that are not in the count:

```
GROUP BY  F_PURCHASE.PID, D_PITEMS.ID, D_PITEMS.ITEMNAME
```